# Highcharts dates in xaxis customisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can we format dates in to this format

[image]

Right now it is like this:

[image]

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        }
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/roydondsouza/3nLmxs89/)

Comment: You mean you dont want to skip dates in xaxis?

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER Thanks for the quick reply. It should look like this [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GgrBB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the code of your xAxis

Here it is :

```
xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
            formatter: function() {

                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.value);

            }
        },

        tickInterval: 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
        },
        {   lineWidth: 0,
           minorGridLineWidth: 0,
           lineColor: 'transparent',
           minorTickLength: 0,
           tickLength: 0,
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value);

            }
        },

        tickInterval: 30 *24 * 3600 * 1000
        }]
```

For details follow this jsFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/3nLmxs89/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, one small doubt - with regard to tweaking end points of months. If chart starts from 30th Jan, we need to show jan as well [**IN THIS JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/roydondsouza/3nLmxs89/2/) what logic could we put for such conditions

Comment: Check out this link.. http://jsfiddle.net/3nLmxs89/3/ , And if solves your problem then please dont forget to upvote and mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will get back to you when I have issues when loading dynamic data. Thanks again.

Comment: Can we make these ticks smarter in anyway? [**JS FIDDLE here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nLmxs89/4/) Thanks again, I owe you one.